# Codeigniter - Can only load model in autoload.php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, model

I'm going crazy because I have been using Codeigniter for ages now and I cannot seem to load a model in my view.

This is what I have done. Model code (**models/changelog.php**):

```
<?php

class Changelog extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function get_list() {
        $query = $this->db->get('changelog');
        return $query->result();        
    }
}

/* Location: ./application/models/changelog.php */
```

This is my controller (**controllers/explore.php**):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Explore extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
    }

    public function changelog() {
        $this->load->model('changelog');
        $data['changelog_row'] = $this->changelog->get_list();

        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('explore/changelog', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
    }
}

/* Location: ./application/controllers/explore.php */
```

I get a Codeigniter notice telling me **Message: Undefined property: Explore::$Changelog** and a PHP error, **Fatal error: Call to a member function get_list() on a non-object**.

Here is what I did

- Tried to autoload the database instead of only loading it in that model
- Tried changing the Changelog call in the contorller to lowercase
- Checked the connection to the database
- Enabled the log file, which doesn't tells me anything new

Everything works correctly, maybe it's just me being a little tired, but if someone could help me out i'd love that :)

---

After some tests I found out the error is in the

```
$data['changelog_row'] = $this->Changelog->get_list();
```

line of my code. I have no idea what the problem is. Case sensitivity is fine (also tried many combinations of lowercase/uppercase), and even if I create another function with different name (e.g. foo()) with a normal echo inside I get the SAME error but referring to that function.

Here is a screen
[image]

---

Something incredible happened: if I add the 'changelog' model in the **autoload.php**, it seems it can actually load it. What is going on? I used this code already in many applications without a problem.

Another test I did: if I write

```
public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('changelog');
}
```

In the controller or just add **parent:: __construct();** in the changelog function like

```
public function changelog() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('changelog');
        $data['changelog_data'] = $this->changelog->get_list();

        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('explore/changelog', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
    }
```

It works O_o. But why? I changed the topic title, now everything is around my inability to load my model in the controller's functions.

Comment: Please change your code in question first. This is not the right way to call a class with capital letter start. First just call the class with lowercase and modify your question in respect of that.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Also check this, che model is actually called with a capital letter in the example: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading

Comment: please see my updated answer. This should work now.

Comment: still nothing. Same error, but I'm updating the main answer since I discovered something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of test and messing up with everything, INCLUDING configuration files... I DID IT!

It was something totally above models and controllers, it was something about the hooks I called. In fact, I have a hook called languageloader.php written like this:

```
class LanguageLoader extends CI_Controller {
    public function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $site_lang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if (!empty($site_lang)) {
            $ci->lang->load('text', $site_lang);
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('text', 'english');
        }
    }
}
```

In my hooks file it was loaded like:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'LanguageLoader',
    'function' => 'initialize',
    'filename' => 'languageloader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

Since I was using **post_controller_constructor**, referring to CI doc files it is

> Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to
>   any method calls happening.

I believe that doing something like my $ci =& get_instance(); I couldn't instance my damn model. I fixed it by changing the hook to

```
$hook['pre_controller']
```

I didn't think it could have been something about the hooks and that was the reasons why I didn't post it. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out in the while. I hope this helped someone else who was in my same trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your `changelog` function with following syntax.

```
public function changelog() {
        $this->load->model('changelog', 'model');
        $data['changelog_row'] = $this->model->get_list();

        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('explore/changelog', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');

}
```

And your model's function should be as follows:

```
public function get_list() {
    $query = $this->db->get('changelog');
    return $query->result();        
}
```

You miss the `public` keyword. So, it is a `private` function now that's why you can't access it from another class.

Comment: Gonna try this asap, may i know why you added 'model' as a second argument in the function call?

Comment: Sure you can know. This is nothing but create a new instances.
That means this did the following task in short:

`$model = new changelog();`

Comment: I have tried this but no luck I still get the same error, no changes. I think that creating the instance could have helped but not in my case

Comment: I have edited the main post adding: "Enabled the log file, which doesn't tells me anything new."

Comment: Its very hard to answer you without see many thing. Please mention your model's file name. And user 'changelog' in lowercase in the controller file.

Comment: Already did and nothing changes. Model name is changelog.php as written in the main topic

Answer (score 1):

CI is acting a bit strange with that.
Om unix systems (where filenames a case sensitive) you have to load the model with case senstive names.
However in the controller you should address it with lowercase, i.e

```
$this->load->model('changeLog');
$this->changelog->getList();
```

Comment: I am respecting case sensitivity, however nothing changes. I updated the main answer!

Comment: Also I would get 'Unable to locate the model you have specified' error, which I don't actually get

Comment: Maybe there is an isue with having the function name equal to the model name, not sure just thinking out loud.

Comment: Tried this already :( I really don't know what to do at this point!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same name for the model as for the controller function so getting name clash because;

```
    $this->changelog()
```

Is trying to refer to the model you have loaded and the class method at the same time.

Rename your Explore::changelog() function (or model name - suffix _m for example) and should be fine. Something like;

```
    $this->changelog_m->getList();
```

Comment: This is not the case unfortunately. Already tried this and nothing changes.

Comment: Also tried with a totally different model just to be sure, called test.php. No luck :(

Comment: Hmm same code in a different model? And still getting the same error?

Comment: Well of course I changed the parts that had to be changed, e.g. "class Test extends CI_Model" and so on. Yeah same error no damn differences. Going crazy.

Comment: The funny thing is that everything is fine if I load the model in autoload.php or in the controller constructor, as described in my main topic..

Comment: Just found out that adding just parent:: __construct(); in the changelog() function it works anyways. What the damn... I updated the main topic anyways..

Comment: Weird dude, i just ran the same code and it worked without issue. Anyway as long as you fixed it!

Comment: Well it is just a SORT of fix, because I have no idea why adding parent:: __construct(); to my function it should work. I don't like to fix things like this - I want to understand what's wrong. Could it be a configuration thing? I didn't touch anything expecial. What CI version are you using?

Comment: 2.2.0. Does it work if you put the parent::__construct() in a controller constructor function? This seems neater and more valid

Comment: No it doesn't. Now I am trying to check some things because I noticed that disabling the hook loading it seems to be working. I need to understand what's wrong

Comment: YES I DID IT. Gonna post my answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, you can modify your autoload.php from

> ./application/config/autoload.php

then just include all you models exist on your model folder

> ./application/models/*_Model.php

So from **autoload.php** set your **autoload['model']** array.

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('first_model', 'second_model');
|
| You can also supply an alternative model name to be assigned
| in the controller:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('first_model' => 'first');
*/
$autoload['model'] = array('Foo_Model', 'Bar_Model', ...);
```

Then from your *Controller* you can remove the `$this->load(...);` from your `__construct()`, since all Models you defined from *autoload.php* is loaded Globally and can be use whenever you run your system.

Then just call directly the public methods you need from that Model, like so;

```
$this->Foo_Model->your_public_method_to_call();
```

**PS:**

- CI_VERSION: 3.x
- PHP: 5.4+

I hope this helps somebody, thanks.